# Calculate ratio of an element in a list efficiently

Tags: list, haskell

The following code works with small lists, however it takes forever with long lists, I suppose it's my double use of length that is the problem.

```
ratioOfPrimes :: [Int] -> Double
ratioOfPrimes xs = fromIntegral (length (filter isPrime xs))/ fromIntegral(length xs)
```

How do I calculate the ratio of an element in longer lists?

Comment: What is taking a long time, `length` or `filter isPrime`?

Comment: How do i measure the time of filter isPrime without printing it?

However it seems like "length $ filter isPrime xs" takes alot longer than just "length xs"

Comment: The definition for isPrime could help too.

Comment: @Vixen See [Criterion](https://github.com/bos/criterion)

Comment: @ZiyaoWei

-- |
from Data.Numbers.Prime
-- Checks whether a given number is prime.
-- 
-- This function uses trial division to check for divisibility with
-- all primes below the square root of the given number. It is
-- impractical for numbers with a very large smallest prime factor.
-- 
isPrime :: Integral int => int -> Bool
isPrime n | n > 1     = primeFactors n == [n]
          | otherwise = False

{-# SPECIALISE isPrime :: Int     -> Bool #-}
{-# SPECIALISE isPrime :: Integer -> Bool #-}

Comment: That isPrime would be very slow. Using sieve / Miller-Rabin would help, and I really don't think you'll get a reasonable timing if you are trying this on a long list with big numbers unless you change to a custom isPrime function implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double use of `length` isn't the main problem here. The multiple traversals in your implementation produce a constant factor and with double `length` and `filter` you get the avg complexity of `O(3n)`. Due to Stream Fusion it's even `O(2n)`, as already mentioned by Impredicative. But in fact since the constant factors don't have a dramatic effect on performance, it's even conventional to simply ignore them, so, conventionally speaking, your implementation still has the complexity of `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the input list.

The real problem here is that the above would all be true only if `isPrime` had the complexity of `O(1)`, but it doesn't. This function performs a traversal thru a list of all primes, so it itself has the complexity of `O(m)`. So the dramatic performance decrease here is caused by your algorithm having the final complexity of `O(n*m)`, because on each iteration of the input list it has to traverse the list of all primes to an unknown depth.

To optimize I suggest to first sort the input list (takes `O(n*log n)`) and itegrate a custom lookup on a list of all primes, which will drop the already visited numbers on each iteration. This way you'll be able to achieve a single traversal on the list of all primes, which theoretically could grant you with the complexity of `O(n*log n + n + m)`, which again, conventionally can be thought of as simply `O(n*log n)`, by highlighting the cost center.

Comment: This does depend somewhat on where the list starts and whether it represents a range - if it involves lots of large, non-contiguous numbers then generating the list of all primes may be slower than a suitably fast primality test.

Comment: @Impredicative Sure, but the bottom line is that `O(n*log n + anyGiantNumber)` scales much better than `O(n*m)`.

Answer (score 3):

So, there's a few things going on there. Let's look at some of the operations involved:

- `length`
- `filter`
- `isPrime`
- `length`

As you say, using `length` twice isn't going to help, since that's `O(n)` for lists. You do that twice. Then there's `filter`, which is also going to do a whole pass of the list in `O(n)`. What we'd like to do is do all this in a single pass of the list.

Functions in the `Data.List.Stream` module implement a technique called Stream Fusion, which would for example rewrite your `(length (filter isPrime xs))` call into a single loop. However, you'd still have the second call to length. You could rewrite this whole thing into a single fold (or use of the State or ST monads) with a pair of accumulators and do this in a single pass:

```
ratioOfPrimes xs = let 
  (a,b) = foldl' (\(odd,all) i -> if (isPrime i) then (odd +1, all+1) else (odd, all+1)) (0,0) xs 
in a/b
```

However, in this case you could also move away from using a list and use the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1) library. The vector library implements the same stream fusion techniques for removing intermediate lists, but also has some other nifty features:

- `length` is `O(1)`
- The `Data.Vector.Unboxed` module lets you store unboxable types (which primitive types such as `Int` certainly are) without the overhead of the boxed representation. So this list of ints would be stored as a low-level `Int` array.

Using the `vector` package should let you write the idiomatic representation you have above and get better than the performance of a single-pass translation.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

ratioOfPrimes :: U.Vector Int -> Double
ratioOfPrimes xs = (fromIntegral $ U.length . U.filter isPrime $ xs) / (fromIntegral $ U.length xs)
```

Of course, the thing that hasn't been mentioned is the `isPrime` function, and whether the real problem is that it's slow for large `n`. An unperformant prime checker could easily blow concerns over list indexing out of the water.

Comment: Will check it out tomorrow, thanks. Lot of things that are beyond my current level of haskell/FP, but that's why I asked.

Comment: Even without fusion, `length (filter p xs)` works in a single pass due to laziness.